# Triple Integral between sphere and plane

Tags: calculus, integration, 3d, volume, spheres

I'm looking through a triple integral example provided by my university, some explanation would be appreciated!

Find the volume between the paraboloid$\ z=x^2+y^2 $ and the plane$\ z=2y $

A visual representation is also provided.

The solution calls for cylindrical coordinates

$\ |R|= \iiint dV $

Bounding$\ z $ coordinates of$\ R $ by

$\ z_{paraboloid} \le z \le z_{plane} $

$\ x^2+y^2 \le 2y \Rightarrow x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1 $

This gives the shadow of$\ R $ on the$\ xy $ plane as a circle of radius$\ r=1 $ centred at$\ (x,y)=(0,1) $. Transforming the equation of this circle to polar coordinates yields

$\ r=2\sin \theta $

Looking at the shadow of$\ R $ on the$\ xy $ plane,$\ r:0 \rightarrow 2 \sin \theta$ (from zero to any point on the boundary of the disk and$\ \theta:0 \rightarrow \pi $.

My issue here is, how are the limits of$\ \theta $ found? I can follow the solution up until this point; any help?

The final integral is the written as

$\ |R|=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\sin\theta}\int_{r^2}^{2r\sin\theta}rdzdrd\theta $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

As you noted the equation of the circle $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ in polar coordinates is $r=2\sin \theta$, but with $0\le \theta \le \pi$ because $r$ must be $\ge 0$.

Comment: Ah, I understand!
When looking at the shadow on the $\ xy $ plane, why is r taken from $\ (x,y)=(0,0) $ rather than the centre of the circle?

Comment: In polar and cylindrical coordinates the radius $r$ is, by definition, the distance from the origin. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system

Comment: Of course! That seemed to escape me. Thank you!
One last question; the reason $\ r $ must be$\ \ge 0 $ is because the shadow is above the line $\ x=0 $? Or can you explain otherwise why $\ r $ must be$\ \ge 0 $?

Comment: $r$ is a distance, so it is $\ge 0$ by definition.

Comment: Ugh, yes. Thank you, I'm just being stupid haha